# Using "pre-defined" iOS push notification sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I would like the play the common iOS push notification sound when the client receives a push message. In another project I used a custom sound what I added to the dictionary like this:

```
    NSString *sound = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"boing.aif"];
    NSDictionary *pushMsg = @{ @"aps" : @{ @"alert" : content, @"sound" : sound } };
```

And I called a method in `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` what played the sound. It works well, but I have no idea how could I do it with system sounds. Do I need to call something in  `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` or add a specific value to the `sound` key in the dictionary?

Comment: Can you please share your code in the didReceiveRemoteNotification ? I've change my Json to sound:default as well but I have no idea how to play the sound when the notification arrives. thank you so much.

Comment: @XcodeNOOB still needed?

Comment: Yes Please... mohen_z@yahoo.com :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `default` for `sound` key in payload

```
"sound" : "default"
```

Comment: I tried it like this  NSDictionary *pushMsg = @{ @"aps" : @{ @"alert" : content, @"sound" : @"default" } };, but unfortunately doesn't works. Do I need to use it differently?

Comment: @gatto, I don't understand where you try to implement it. Do you have some API to push in your application? What do you do with pushMsg dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, I tested it on a wrong device. Your answer is totally correct.